# AWS CodeDeploy for ECS EC2 Blue/Green Deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, aws-codepipeline, aws-code-deploy

I'm trying to deploy my product by using CodePipeline with CodeDeploy for ECS EC2 Blue/Green Deploy but it always return this error when it run:

> Container.image contains invalid characters.

I think the error come from 2 files **appspec.yaml** and **taskdef.json** because when I using Rolling Deploy, it worked.

This is my config:

*appspec.yaml*

```
version: 0.0
Resources:
 - TargetService:
     Type: AWS::ECS::Service
     Properties:
       TaskDefinition: <TASK_DEFINITION>
       LoadBalancerInfo:
         ContainerName: "my-container"
         ContainerPort: 80
```

*taskdef.json*

```
{
  "ipcMode": null,
  "executionRoleArn": null,
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "dnsSearchDomains": null,
      "environmentFiles": null,
      "logConfiguration": null,
      "entryPoint": null,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 80,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "containerPort": 80
        },
        {
          "hostPort": 8000,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "containerPort": 8000
        }
      ],
      "command": null,
      "linuxParameters": null,
      "cpu": 0,
      "environment": [],
      "resourceRequirements": null,
      "ulimits": null,
      "dnsServers": null,
      "mountPoints": [],
      "workingDirectory": null,
      "secrets": null,
      "dockerSecurityOptions": null,
      "memory": null,
      "memoryReservation": null,
      "volumesFrom": [],
      "stopTimeout": null,
      "image": "<IMAGE1_NAME>",
      "startTimeout": null,
      "firelensConfiguration": null,
      "dependsOn": null,
      "disableNetworking": null,
      "interactive": null,
      "healthCheck": null,
      "essential": true,
      "links": null,
      "hostname": null,
      "extraHosts": null,
      "pseudoTerminal": null,
      "user": null,
      "readonlyRootFilesystem": null,
      "dockerLabels": null,
      "systemControls": null,
      "privileged": null,
      "name": "my-container"
    }
  ],
  "placementConstraints": [],
  "memory": "512",
  "taskRoleArn": null,
  "compatibilities": [
    "EXTERNAL",
    "EC2"
  ],
  "taskDefinitionArn": "<TASK_DEFINITION>",
  "family": "task-definition-name",
  "requiresAttributes": [
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.ecr-auth"
    }
  ],
  "pidMode": null,
  "requiresCompatibilities": [
    "EC2"
  ],
  "networkMode": null,
  "cpu": "512",
  "revision": 17,
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "inferenceAccelerators": null,
  "proxyConfiguration": null,
  "volumes": []
}
```

My config are following these posts:

https://www.proud2becloud.com/how-to-setup-a-continuous-deployment-pipeline-on-aws-for-ecs-blue-green-deployments/
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/action-reference-ECSbluegreen.html

I have tried to find the solution for this but still nothing work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If I look at [this summary reference](https://ecsworkshop.com/blue_green_deployments/config-files/) it looks like some of your parameters are misplaced?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation on this is generally poor.

In your task definition you have: "**image": "<IMAGE1_NAME>**"

Within your pipeline definition you need a file, specifically named  **imageDetail.json**

It needs to be exactly like the following, with the relevant Docker Image.

```
{"ImageURI":"???????.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/???/???:????"}
```

If your pipeline is using ECR as the Source to trigger the pipeline then it creates it for you I think, if not you need to create it for yourself.

For example, In my pipeline I don't use ECR as the source, I compile the code, create and push the image and then produce the imageDetail.json using a CodeBuild project, the output of which is named **BuildDockerOutput**

```
            - Name: BlueGreenDeploy
              InputArtifacts:
              - Name: PrepareCodeDeployOutputProd
              - Name: BuildDockerOutput
              Region: !Ref DeployRegion1
              ActionTypeId:
                Category: Deploy
                Owner: AWS
                Version: '1'
                Provider: CodeDeployToECS
              RoleArn: !Sub arn:aws:iam::${ProdAccountId}:role/CrossAccountsDeploymentRole
              Configuration:

                AppSpecTemplateArtifact: PrepareCodeDeployOutputProd
                AppSpecTemplatePath: appspec.json

                ApplicationName: !Ref ApplicationName
                DeploymentGroupName: !Ref ApplicationName
                
                TaskDefinitionTemplateArtifact: PrepareCodeDeployOutputProd
                TaskDefinitionTemplatePath: taskdef.json

                Image1ArtifactName: BuildDockerOutput
                Image1ContainerName: "IMAGE1_NAME"
```

Artifact **BuildDockerOutput is an input** to the CodeDeploy Stage and it substitutes the <IMAGE1_NAME> placeholder with value of **ImageURI** from  imageDetail.json.

Note I never specify the file name.

Comment: Thank you. I changed "image": "<IMAGE1_NAME>" to the image uri and it worked. However, there is a problem with ALB since the target group always return "Request timed out" or "Health check failed". I'm using multi port mapping in host.

Comment: You are welcome. check the exposed port from your dockerfile your container is listening on. Make sure the health check is against an exposed port, make sure the target group health check is against an exposed port and make sure the target security group allows inbound connections to this port from the load balancer security group.

Comment: @RonanCunningham can you please elaborate on the "Make sure the health check is against an exposed port, make sure the target group health check is against an exposed port". How do i expose these ports?